# Is Operator Overriding supported by C#

Tags: c#, overriding

I have gone to an interview where I was asked to answer a question:

> Is operator overriding supported by C#?

I know that operator overloading is supported but I have no idea about overriding a operator. Is it possible?

Comment: This is an extremely easily google'd question.  What have you tried?

Comment: To be fair: it is not so easy to google. Because it does not exists, you don't get useful hits. Check these results: https://www.google.com/search?q=Operator+Overriding+C%23

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, operator overriding is not supported. The term Overriding is used when a method is inherited by a subclass and the subclass overrides it with its own implementation. Operators are all static in C# and cannot be overridden.

Overloading means that another method with the same name but a different signature (arguments) is defined. That's what you can do with operators.

This is extremely important to know when writing operators in C#. The operator is bound at compile time. The effective type which is passed to the operator at runtime is not important at all.

Eg. you write some comparison operator

```
public static bool operator==(MyClass c1, MyClass c2)
{
  //...
}
```

And have the following code:

```
object myObj1 = new MyClass();
object myObj2 = new MyClass();

if (myObj1 == myObj2)
//...
```

object's operator will be called, not your own, because the
arguments are references of type object.

Comment: Just to note, we need to write `!=` operator with same parameter also.